# Unable to run a POST action in play framework 2.2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a similar problem to [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769805/unable-to-run-a-post-test-in-play-framework) and I am unsure why.

my post action is called from a form submission and the controller code

```
  def processFreeDoc = UserAwareAction {
    implicit request => {
      userEmailForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => {
          Logger.error("Error processing the form %s "format formWithErrors.errors)
          Redirect(routes.Application.index)
        },
        data => {
          val sessionProduct = getSessionUnProcessedProduct(data.sessionId, data.documentName)
          if(sessionProduct != null){
            Logger.info("Found")
            sessionProduct.updateProcessing(data.emailAddress, data.sessionId)
            Redirect(routes.Application.index)
          }
          else
            Logger.info("Nothing found")
            Redirect(routes.Application.checkoutFree(data.sessionId))

        }
      )

    }
  }
```

is skipped entirely. There are no errors in the IDE(IDEA) console and the breakpoint at the entry of the method is not reached so none of the log messages are seen.

EDIT :
The relevant route in the routes file - **POST /processFreeDoc                   controllers.Application.processFreeDoc**

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the relevant parts of your routes file and the (Curl command?) you're actually using to test this. At first glance the most likely culprit would seem to be whatever is happening inside `UserAwareAction`.

Comment: I suspect a `BodyParser` issue with `UserAwareAction`.

Comment: @Mikesname I'm working with this in IDE so I am debugging / testing the site as is.